# BMO 1 1999 Base 3 recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series

A positive integer $m$ can be written uniquely in base $3$ as a string of 0's, 1's or 2's. let $c(m)$ denote the sum of the cube of the digits of the base 3 representation of $m$ for example $c(98)=1^3+0^3+1^3+2^3+2^3=18$

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer, define the sequence $u_r$ by $u_1=n$ and $u_r=c(u_{r-1})$ for $r\ge2$ show that there is a postive integer $r$ such that $u_r=1,2,17$ (ie a term in the sequence for which $u_r$ takes one of these values)

Comment: I is not true for all $n$.  Just take $n=1$  Are you supposed to find such an $n$?  I suspect you are supposed to show that for any $n$ you will reach one of $1,2,$ or $17$.  Note that $1$ and $17$ are fixed points of $c$ and $2$ is part of the cycle $2,8,16,10,2$

Comment: Is the question that $u_r$ is *one of* these values?

Comment: Yes sorry about that, but it is true for n=1 because $u_2=1$ as required to prove.

Comment: Yes the question clearly states that you show for any n you will eventually reach 1,2,7

Comment: $1, 2, 7$ or $1, 2, 17?$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $c(1)=1, c(17)=17$ and $c(2)=8, c(8)=16, c(16)=10, c(10)=2$ so once you hit one of these values you will cycle forever.  The basic idea is to show that if $n$ is large enough, $c(n) \lt n$.  You start with the fact that $c(n)$ can be no greater than $8$ times the number of base $3$ digits in $n$.  It is pretty easy to show that this is true for all $n \ge 32$.  Then you can just show that all numbers less than $32$ end up in one of these cycles.

Comment: How do I show this is true for n is greater than 32?

Comment: You use the fact I quoted about $c(n)$ can be no greater than $8$ times the number of base $3$ digits.  $32$ has four digits in base $3$.  Every larger four digit number will have $c(n) \lt n$.  Five digit numbers start at $81$ and $5 \cdot 8$ is only $40$.